# create knitr chunks that don't change the random seed?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In an rmarkdown document, I'd like to optionally create chunks that don't affect the global random seed when they are run. The idea is similar in logic to, say, `R.utils`'s [withSeed](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.10.1/topics/withSeed) function that runs some code with a specified random seed, then the random seed gets reset to what it was before the code was run.

I've thought of a way to do with with `knitr` hooks:

````
---
title: Test
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
set.seed(123)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

knitr::knit_hooks$set(no_seed = function(before, options, envir) {
  # See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Numbers/Saving_the_state_of_the_random_number_generator/  
  if (before){
    initial_seed <- NULL
    if(exists(".Random.seed", .GlobalEnv))
      initial_seed = get(".Random.seed", .GlobalEnv)
    assign(".initial_seed", initial_seed, envir = envir)
  }else{
    if(exists(".initial_seed", envir = envir)){
      initial_seed = get(".initial_seed", envir)
      if(!is.null(initial_seed)){
        assign(".Random.seed", initial_seed, envir = .GlobalEnv)
      }else{
        rm(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv)
      }
      rm(".initial_seed", envir = envir)
    }
  }
})

# A function to summarise the state of the RNG in a hash
seed_digest = function(){
  ifelse(exists(".Random.seed", .GlobalEnv),
         digest::digest(.GlobalEnv$.Random.seed),
         NA)
}

```

## Chunk 1

```{r}
seed_digest()
rnorm(3)
seed_digest()
```


## Interloper chunk


```{r no_seed=TRUE}
seed_digest()
rnorm(3)
```


## Chunk 2

```{r}
seed_digest()
rnorm(3)
```
````

The knitr hook `no_seed` has a "before" and "after" component. In the before component, it saves the current state of the RNG in the environment in a variable called `.initial_seed`. Ater the chunk is run, the variable is read and the random seed reset to what it was.

However, this creates a side effect in the environment in which the code is being run, which is undesirable. Is there a better way of doing this that does not have a side effect, is more elegant, or more robust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If functions need persistent storage, you can use `local()` to create an environment to hold it and it will not interfere with anything else.  Here's a modification of your code that does this:

```r
hook_fn <- local({
  initial_seed <- NULL
  
  function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before){
      initial_seed <<- if(exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits=FALSE)) 
                         .Random.seed
    }else{
      if(!is.null(initial_seed))
        .Random.seed <<- initial_seed
      else
        rm(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
  }
})

knitr::knit_hooks$set(no_seed = hook_fn)
```

This allows a fair bit of simplification:

- `initial_seed` is known to exist in the function's environment (the parent of the evaluation environment), so `<<-` will make assignments to it.
- `.GlobalEnv` is known to be the parent of that local environment, so if `.Random.seed` exists there, it's the one the function will see.
- If `.Random.seed` doesn't exist in `.GlobalEnv`, the `initial_seed` will be set to `NULL` because the `if` has no `else` clause.

Comment: That's great! Thanks very much.